# How to secure code in shared development in Linux?

Tags: linux, git, tfs, codeblocks

How to secure code in shared development in Linux where a developer is allowed to develop and test its module with existing code but cannot commit final changes to main code without permission and must not be able to copy the code?

We are using Code::Blocks for c++ development purpose.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Do you want to prevent unauthorized merges into some trunk branch? Or something else? Also "must not be able to copy the code" is not possible if you want them to be able to read/write the code; any technical solution can be circumvented simply by typing the code by hand on another computer.

Comment: Yes, first i want to prevent unauthorized merges and want to protect the code from misuse

Comment: Please define "protect the code from misuse".

Comment: @ScottWeldon Misuse means copy and sharing with unwanted groups / team

Comment: See the latter part of my first comment. If you trust your developers enough to allow them to read and edit the code, you should trust them enough to not share it with unauthorized parties; there is no middle ground.

Comment: @Shailendrakumar In Git, users could read and edit code in their local repository, if you deny the permission like I posted below, them can't check in to server side. So it won't affect others code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your developers to push code to the repository to TFS server side but still want to get and edit them at local side. You could **Deny** the **Contributor permission** for your Git repository. Then uses at that TFS group could still clone and edit code at local repository but they can't push them to server side.

[image]

Also, I suggest that you could [add a Branch policy with Code review](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies#require-code-reviews) for your Master branch when some one when you merge code to it, it needs to do a [Pull request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/pull-requests).